# Reroute messages in DLQ to process again on a rest call

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, dlq

I am using `spring cloud stream function` with `kafka bindings` to process my messages. I have also configured my `DLQ` like this

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        group: abs
      function.definition: abc|def|ghi
      kafka:
        binder:
        
        bindings:
          abcdefghi-in-0:
            consumer:
              enable-dlq: true
              dlq-name: a.b.c.deadletter
              dlq-producer-properties:
                configuration:
                  schema.registry.url: ${kafka.schema.registry.url}
                  key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
                  value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer
          
      bindings:
        abcdefghi-in-0:
          destination: a.b.c.in
          content-type: application/x-protobuf
```

And I have 3 `java.util.functions` to process the message one after the other as per the configuration.

I am trying to put the messages in the `DLQ-a.b.c.deadletter` back to input such a way that this message will be again processed by my 3 functions again. How can I do this upon a `rest` call?

I was looking at [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.0.RC1/multi/multi_kafka-dlq-processing.html), but I don't want to use `@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)` as it is deprecated and also I wanted it to be triggered from a rest call.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to process the messages from the DLT. And you want to use the same composed function sequence - `abc|def|ghi`. That may not be possible since the original `abcdefghi-in-0` binding is bound to a topic already (`a.b.c.in`).

Comment: You can come up with another function, that is bound with the input destination of `a.b.c.deadletter` and then manually re-route that by calling abc, def and ghi. Or create another compostion like - `xyz|abc|def|ghi` with your DLT destination as input.